# Receiving bounced spam messages sent from my domain

Tags: security, email, sendmail, spam, postfix-mta

I recently noticed my gmail spam folder had some bounced messages to my business email address (which is configured to forward to my gmail). After some investigation it appears as though someone is using my domain name and randomly generated usernames as return address on their spam emails.

Mail.log shows these messages coming in, but not being sent. Is it possible that my server (Postfix or sendmail) is allowing a user to push out emails without generating log entries? What is the likelihood that somebody is spoofing my domain (not a very popular one at all) and not actually sending from my server?

Most importantly, what can I do to prevent spam emails from being sent out with my name on them, if anything? I'm concerned that gmail at least will mark me as a spammer since all the bounced spam messages are going to my gmail as though they were sent from my domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the spamassassin in your server and connect it to the postfix. SpamAssassin uses a wide variety of local and network tests to identify spam signatures. This makes it harder for spammers to identify one aspect which they can craft their messages to work around.

It is very easy to config,SpamAssassin requires very little configuration; you do not need to continually update it with details of your mail accounts, mailing list memberships, etc. Once classified, site and user-specific policies can then be applied against spam. Policies can be applied on both mail servers and later using the user's own mail user-agent application.

You can refer the [link](http://spamassassin.apache.org/doc.html) to know more about the spamassassin